# Adjust document height after an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, height, document

I would like to change the document height after an ajax call. Why to do that? Because in my web page I have different buttons to navigate (go to the first page, to the last, to one specific) and the data is loaded by ajax, but if the data loaded is less tall than before I get an extra blank at the end.

For example, if the document and the body was 3400 height previous to the call and I go to the last page, and that page has less data, the body turns 2400 height, but the document keeps the 3400 height.

So I would like to change the height of the document. I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
if(jQuery(document).height() > jQuery('html').height()){
  jQuery(document).height(jQuery('html').height());
}
```

Any ideas? It's possible to "resize" the document after an ajax call?

Comment: Why don't you use css 'auto' .. make your height auto so that it fits your text automatically..

Comment: That was not supposed to happen. You probably have some js or CSS fixing the height. Just find and remove it.

Comment: document is not a html tag. You should use 'body' instead

Comment: @tborychowski it's a jQuery tag :)

Comment: @Morpheus jQuery does not have tags. You can get "document" using jQuery, but you can't style "document" using css, as it is not html

Comment: @tborychowski you can't style "document", but you can get height :)

Comment: How do you know that the document is maintaining its height after the body height changes? Are you setting a fixed height somewhere? What are you setting the height on? Can you provide an example?